# How to test the APNS p12 certificate environments ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, security, apple-push-notifications, ssl-certificate

I'm developing a service for sending push notifications, but I can't tell if the uploaded apns certificate p12 is from sandbox or production. I would like to test this in order to avoid human error when uploading the certificate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a few changes to the code suggested by muenzpraeger.

```
require 'openssl'

# If you want to read a .p12 cert

raw_cert = OpenSSL::PKCS12.new(File.read(path_to_your_cert), your_pwd) 

OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(raw_cert).subject.to_s.include? "Apple Production"
```

Answer (score 1):

The common name of the issued certificate tells you if it's from sandbox or production.

Example for production: *Apple Production IOS Push Services: your.app.identifier*

My ruby skills are a bit rusty but this should do it:

```
require 'openssl'
raw_cert = OpenSSL::PKCS12.new(File.read(path_to_your_cert), your_pwd) # If you want to read a .p12 cert

cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(raw_cert)
cert.subject.start_with?("Apple Production IOS")
```

See also here: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/X509/Certificate.html

Comment: Thanks I've made a few changes to the code but it worked.

`OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(raw_cert).subject.to_s.include? "Apple Production" `